# Cannot Resolve Symbol android studio

Tags: android, resources, symbols, resolve

I'm a beginner in Android Studio, I'm trying to work with fragments through a tutorial on youtube. Problem is, in the video he uses a method onAttach(Activity), but when I try to use it, it tells me it's deprecated and I should use onAttach(Context), but then when I try to run the program it crashes. It shows imported classes in red in the Resource class, and when I hover with my mouse on the troubled classes it says that Cannot Resolve Symbol.

What should I do?

Comment: post your fragment code here, and any relevant logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP here! So I managed to solve the problem, and so it is!
in order to get the activity in the `onAttach(Context context)`, simply use casting, for example
`Activity activity = (Activity) context;`.
Now as for them Symbol Resolving issue, go to `Build -> Clean Project`, that seemed to fix some errors, but the app didn't work just yet, it showed I had an error with a photo I was using, so I just imported it with a BMP format instead of the original jpeg.
Hope this helps someone!